EC2 machines: python SSHTunnelForwarder closing tunnel on the background when high number of connections made
I have GRPC services running on EC2 machines and an orchestrator that connects to those machines through SSHTunnelForwarder.
This works fine when I am running low number of servers (arround 4 to 8). But when I try to run with higher volume up to 40 services the tunnels close on the background and tunnels switch from is_active=True to is_active=False.
But did not really help. I am using EC2 M5 machine with 4cpus for orchestration.
I changed the setting to enable higher service using:
sed -i '/^#MaxSessions/c\MaxSessions 100' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i '/^#MaxStartups/c\MaxStartups 100:30:200' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

but still failed to connect.
I checked the network bandwidth and does not seem to hit it nor the cpu usage / memory usage limits. Any other ideas to check are welcome.
Thanks

Looks to be related to the SSHTunnelForwarder on:
ptyhon==3.10.0
with packages:
crypt==4.1.1
paramiko==3.4.0
sshtunnel==0.4.0
Locally I am running with 3.9.7 and issue not happening.
Also, when I created the tunnels before calling python using cmd
ssh -i "myKey" -L 50052:localhost:50052 user@targetMachine

the issue is resolved on ec2 machines.
